# Add "unused" text to input field box?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I currently have:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" style="height:40px;width:200px;font-size:23px;text-align:center;" value="${$amount}" />
```

This is the part I'm specifically talking about:

```
value="${$amount}"
```

By default that shows `$10.00` which is what I want.  However, I don't want users to be able to edit the `$` symbol.  It should always remain there AND I don't want the dollar symbol submitted with the form.  It's simply there for appearance so that users know the currency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the dollar sign as a background image for the input and leave some padding-left so that the text doesn't go over the background image.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pseudo element.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tz76a92h/1/)

```
<label>Label</label>
<span><input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder"></span>
```

---

```
input {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

span:before {
    content: "$";
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Requires a wrapper element around your input as you cant generate a pseudo element on an input

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to put the sign outside the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mgmBE/45/

HTML:

```html
<div class="input-container">
<input type="text" value="amount" name="" />
<span class="unit">$</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.input-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
    .input-container input {
    width: 100%;
}

.input-container .unit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: -3px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `<span>` set to `display:block` instead of a `<div>`?

Comment: @flowstoneknight no sorry i did'nt notice it

Answer (score 0):

[Pseudo Element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) is the best option as very easy to place.

```
<label>Input:</label><span><input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder"></span>
```

CSS

```
input {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left:15px;
}

span:before {
    content: "$";
    margin-right:-15px;
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
}
```